# My Discord Bot [C#] Is online, Connected in the App but does not respond to any commands

Tags: c#, bots, discord.net

So I wanted to make a discord bot that would pick a random character in game for me and my friends while we are on discord and I just can't make it work. When I run the project in visual studio there are no errors, it says connected. The bot goes online, but when I try to use any command (ping) it does nothing

This is my main script for the

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace GaryBot
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private CommandService _commands;
        private IServiceProvider _services;

        public async Task RunBotAsync()
        {
            var configuracoes = new DiscordSocketConfig()
            {
                GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.Guilds | GatewayIntents.GuildMessages
            };
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient(configuracoes);
            _commands = new CommandService();

            _services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(_client)
                .AddSingleton(_commands)
                .BuildServiceProvider();

        string token = "XXX";

            _client.Log += _client_Log;

            await RegisterCommandsAsync();

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);

            await _client.StartAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task _client_Log(LogMessage arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
        {
            _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);

        }

        private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
        {
            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);
            if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

            int argPos = 0;
            if(message.HasStringPrefix("]", ref argPos))
            {
                var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);
                if (!result.IsSuccess) Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Commands script

```
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GaryBot.Modules
{
    public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("ping")]
        public async Task Ping()
        {
            await ReplyAsync("Pong");
        }
    }
}
```

I searched multiple threads and nothing worked for me

Comment: Suppose you've missed to grant access to message content with `GatewayIntents.MessageContent` in your `configuracoes`.